# reading tomcat7 configurations from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, tomcat7, jruby

I want to read a couple of Tomcat characters like maxThreads, maxConnections etc so that I can expose them through one of the API endpoints. Tomcat will be hosting my app WAR file.

Answer (score 0):

use JMX for that (Tomcat exposes its configuration as an MBean)

... there's MBean APIs in Java which you can script using JRuby.